# jQuery custom plugin element counter

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I am creating jQuery plugin which counts how many elements there are in the DOM.

This is what I have done so far.

**jQuery Plugin**

```
$.fn.count = function(i) {
  return this.each(function() {
    ++i;
    return i;
  });
}
```

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<body>
  <p>Sample text.</p> 
  <p>Sample text.</p>
  <p>Sample text.</p>      
</body>
</html>
```

**Running the plugin**

```
console.log($("p").count());
```

**Error**

[image: inspect element]

**Expected Output**

```
3
```

What am I missing in the plugin? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Why you want this??? you can easily find count of any tag by using find method of jQuery. Use this to find count.  alert($( "#body" ).find( "p" ).length);

Comment: I know that I could use that however, I am playing around with jQuery plugins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your plugin you are returning `this` i:e nothing but the `<p>` remove that.

```
$.fn.count = function () {
    var j = 0;
    this.each(function () {
        ++j;
    });
    return j;
}
```

Why do not use `length` property to find count of elements in dom.

Comment: I know that I could use the `length` property however, I am playing around with jQuery plugins. Also, thanks for the answer!! :)